# Visual Studio 2010 Solution problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, installation, solution

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC2 website and now I need to add more projects. My current webproject looks like this :

```
MyProject
- MyProject
-- [MyProjects project files]
- [Solution files] (plus a webconfig)
```

I started to takeout just the MyProject and rename it so that the structure looked like this :

```
MyProject.Website
- [MyPrject.Website project files]
```

Then I Created a MyPrject folder where I placed both the MyProjectSite and another project called MyProject.Integration, like this :

```
MyProject
- MyProject.Website
- MyProject.Integration
```

Then I started Visual Studio 2010 and created a blank solution, this gave me the following file structure :

```
MyProject
- MyProject.Solution
-- [Solution files] (no web.config)
- MyProject.Website
-- [Website project files]
- MyProject.Integration
-- [Integration project files)
```

When looking in Visual Studio 2010 I can see that my Solution(MyProject) contains two projects(MyProject.Website and MyPrject.Integration).

Now I hit Rebuild all and first get the following Exception:

**Error 1   Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config 129**

If I just rebuild the MyProjectIntegration everything is working fine but uts when building the MyProject.Website that I get this exception.

Its strange that I get a exception in a web.config not placed within my projects?

I googled the problem and found out that I could add a row to my web.config in the MyProject.Website, this is how it looks

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

*The "System.Data.Entity.Design" row was added*

When this was dune I rebuilded again and then I got the following exception :

**Error 1   The type or namespace name 'ModelViewRegisterFilter' does not exist in the namespace 'Biss.Views.ViewClasses' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyProject.website\e0c6b507\13ca6533\App_Web_3ri01j0f.0.cs 178**

What am I doing wrong? I just need to have a main Solution that contains the two projects?

**Edit1:** Pleas note that all the projects was working just fine before I tried to place them in this solution.

Comment: Go to this link, you will get an idea, http://forums.asp.net/t/1546705.aspx

Comment: As I said, I have already googled the exception and I did the change as you can see. This does however generate another exceptio, I supose that this is wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a blank solution, why not try starting off with the mvc solution template and then add your existing projects and files to it.

Comment: Because the filestructure will not be correct according to my post.

Comment: I tested your solution and with some work I got it to work, The file structure is not execly as I wanted it to be (no special Solution folder) but I can live with that. The question do however remains, why did I get the problem in my post?

Answer (score 5):

when I got this issue, I just added the following line on compilation/assemblies on web.config:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```